# How to maximize small business 401k contribution?

Tags: united-states, 401k, small-business, contribution

We own small business (C-Corp *without* S-election) that currently does not have employees outside the owners (three of us). The business is producing a nice amount of revenue and as of yet none of us have drawn any salary.

We'd like to set up a 401k plan for the business and maximize our contributions. Reading up on the subject, the individual contribution limit for 2016 is $18,000 and the total of individual + employer match is $53,000.

What's the minimum salary we need to pay ourselves and overall structure to enable that maximum $53,000 value per person?

Can we pay ourselves a $18,000 salary with 100% personal contribution to the 401k as well as a $35,000 employer contribution for a total of $53,000? Or do we need to pay ourselves a higher salary to allow for the maximum?

*To clarify further, we're trying to figure out the minimum we have to pay out in salary and employer match to maximize the $53,000 total per person limit. We're not sure if the outline in the previous paragraph ($18K salary all going to 401k as individual component and $35K employer contribution) is allowed and, if not, what's the minimum outlay from the company that would be allowed?*

Comment: Do a SEP instead.  Much higher limits, around 51K per year and pretty much free to setup.  Check with your CPA.

Comment: A SEP limits contributions to 25% of wages so we'd have to pay out higher wages which would be additional taxable income (that we're looking to avoid). That's why I'm specifically asking about structuring a 401k/payroll to get the max 401k contribution of $53K.

Comment: How is your business organized?  LLC, partnership, etc.?  Did you make an explicit election with the IRS to be taxed in a certain way (like S-Corp) or are you taxed under the default rules for your category?

Comment: It's a C-corp and we don't have (and have no plans to get) an S-election. I added that to the question description.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has thrown out the off-topic mention yet, since this question isn't about personal finance. That being said, given that there isn't a good business accounting SE site yet (there probably should be?), I'd personally vote to let this one stay despite it being off topic.

Comment: I just proposed a new business accounting and law site if anyone's interested: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99203/business-accounting-and-law

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that to make the $18,000 elective deferral in this case, you need to pay yourself at least $18,000.  There will be some tax on that for social security and Medicare, so you'll actually need to pay yourself a bit more to cover that too.

The employer contribution is limited to 25% of your total compensation.  The $18,000 above counts, but if you want to max out on the employer side, you'll need to pay yourself $140,000 salary since 25% of $140,000 is the $35,000 that you want to put into the 401k from the employer side.

There are some examples from the IRS here that may help:
https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/one-participant-401-k-plans
I know that you're not a one-participant plan, but some of the examples may help anyway since they are not all specific to one-participant plans.

Comment: I keep finding conflicting info on the max contribution made by the employer. Your link indicates 25% of salary, but this link indicates up to 100% of salary (lesser of 100% or $53K). And I find blogs that indicate each is correct. Or, is it really just for super-high salaries that this comes into play? Thoughts? https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/401k-plans-deferrals-and-matching-when-compensation-exceeds-the-annual-limit

Comment: Do you have a source for the employer contribution being limited to 25% of the employees total compensation? I can't find that anywhere

Comment: @Bishop - Check the link in Brick's answer, under "Employer nonelective contributions".

Comment: The 25% is in the link in the answer, but I have to admit that I'm confused with the apparently different limits shown in the answer by @BobbyScon and link therein. If someone puts up a believable answer that reconciles both, I'll probably delete my answer completely.

Comment: @Brick - I believe it's based on business type. Your link seems to refer to One-Participant plans (covering a business owner with no employees), whereas my link seems to be Multi-Participant plans. I'm not familiar enough with setting up a 401K plan to know if a 3-person C-Corp qualifies for the Multi-Participant plan scenario.

Comment: Brick is correct. Source: I'm a Third Party Administrator

Comment: @Chris so for a non-solo 401k (i.e. 3 person C-Corp) we'd need to have a salary of at least 4x (1 / .25) the employer contribution? Ex: (53000 - 18000) / .25  = $140,000 salary to be able to max things out?

Comment: @SamuelRodgers Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 401K information from the IRS' website, it seems that you could seemingly get away with a salary as low as $53,000. It's tough, and I'd suggest speaking with an Accounting professional to get the clear answers, because as Brick's answer suggests, the IRS isn't super clear about it.

An excerpt from a separate page regarding 401K contributions:

> The annual additions paid to a participant’s account cannot exceed the
>   lesser of:
>
> 1. 100% of the participant's compensation, or
> 2. $53,000 ($59,000 including catch-up contributions) for 2015 and 2016.
>
> There are separate, smaller limits for SIMPLE 401(k) plans.
>
> Example 1: Greg, 46, is employed by an employer with a 401(k) plan and
>   he also works as an independent contractor for an unrelated business.
>   Greg sets up a solo 401(k) plan for his independent contracting
>   business. Greg contributes the maximum amount to his employer’s 401(k)
>   plan for 2015, $18,000. Greg would also like to contribute the maximum
>   amount to his solo 401(k) plan. He is not able to make further
>   elective deferrals to his solo 401(k) plan because he has already
>   contributed his personal maximum, $18,000. He has enough earned income
>   from his business to contribute the overall maximum for the year,
>   $53,000. Greg can make a nonelective contribution of $53,000 to his
>   solo 401(k) plan. This limit is not reduced by the elective deferrals
>   under his employer’s plan because the limit on annual additions
>   applies to each plan separately.

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-401k-and-profit-sharing-plan-contribution-limits

Answer (score 1):

I would hire an accountant to help set this up, given the sums of money involved.

$53,000 would be the minimum amount of compensation needed to maximize the 401k. The [total limit of contributions](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-401k-and-profit-sharing-plan-contribution-limits) is the lesser of:

> 100% of the participant's compensation, or
>
> $53,000 ($59,000 including catch-up contributions) for 2015 and 2016.

and they don't count contributions as [compensation](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p525.pdf)

> Your employer's contributions to a qualified retirement plan for you
>   are not included in income at the time contributed. (Your employer can
>   tell  you  whether  your  retirement  plan  is  qualified.)

On the bright side, employer contributions aren't subject to [FICA withholdings](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/retirement-plan-faqs-regarding-contributions-are-retirement-plan-contributions-subject-to-withholding-for-fica-medicare-or-federal-income-tax).